# MathJax rendering bug: wrong interaction between "\tfrac" or "\frac" and "\left[ ... \right]"

Tags: bug, mathjax

The code `\left[ \dfrac 1 2 \right]` displays *correctly* inline as $\left[ \dfrac 1 2 \right]$ and *correctly* in display mode as $$\left[ \dfrac 1 2 \right] .$$

The code `\left[ \tfrac 1 2 \right]` displays *incorrectly* inline as $\left[ \tfrac 1 2 \right]$ and *incorrectly* in display mode as $$\left[ \tfrac 1 2 \right] .$$

The code `\left[ \frac 1 2 \right]` displays *incorrectly* inline as $\left[ \frac 1 2 \right]$ and *correctly* in display mode as $$\left[ \frac 1 2 \right] .$$

When I say "incorrectly", I mean that I what see is $\lfloor \dots \rfloor$ ("floor" function brackets) instead of square brackets.

Does this happen only locally, on my computer? Do things render the same for you? Even though I don't like external links, clicking 
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRPJu.png) will display a screen capture of this page as displayed on my computer, hosted under SE account of ImgUr.

Comment: I see square brackets everywhere

Comment: I don't see it. Do you happen to have a high-DPI screen? There was a similar issue with `\sqrt`, the line was less than 1px high and so wasn't displayed on a high-DPI screen. I guess the same thing happens here. When you zoom in and out does the appearance change?

Comment: Try setting the zoom to 99% or 101% and see if that fixes the problem. (Right click, Math Settings, Scale all math)

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: I don't have a high-DPI screen. It displays correctly if I zoom in and out at the page level (i.e. using browser commands, not MathJax commands).

Comment: @AsafKaragila: 99% and 101% don't solve the problem, but it seems that everything $\le 95 \%$ or $\ge 108 \%$ solves it.

Comment: I'm saying, because [I had a similar issue once](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1420/math-font-render-problem).

Comment: @alex M. Could you add a screenshot as well as browser and OS version. Also, the info in MathJax's About panel (via the MathJax menu) would help.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger: The screenshot is included as a link at the very end of my post. The OS is Windows XP SP3 (with the all the latest patches). The browser is the latest stable Firefox, 43.0.4.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger: About MathJax says: MathJax.js v2.6.0
TeX Input Jax v2.6.0
HTML-CSS Output Jax v2.6.0
PreviewHTML Output Jax v2.6.0
mml Element Jax v2.6.0
AssistiveMML Extension v2.6.0
MathEvents Extension v2.6.0
MathMenu Extension v2.6.0
MathZoom Extension v2.6.0
TeX/AMSmath Extension v2.6.0
TeX/AMSsymbols Extension v2.6.0
TeX/noErrors Extension v2.6.0
TeX/noUndefined Extension v2.6.0
fast-preview Extension v2.6.0
tex2jax Extension v2.6.0
Firefox v43.0 — woff or otf fonts

Comment: Thanks for the follow up (and sorry I missed the screenshot earlier). I will try to reproduce it; it might be a duplicate of https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/1009.

Comment: You might want to switch to the CommonHTML output in the mean time.

Comment: @Peter: That explains why displayed integral signs looked a bit weird to me recently.

Comment: @Asaf try the CommonHTML output. It's faster and shouldn't have the issue.

Comment: @Peter: Not sure about faster (not slower, though, that's for sure), but it did solve that problem.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger: I confirm that HTML-CSS is currently the only available rendering mode exhibiting my problem.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, @AlexM.

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger: I also believe it's not a purely Firefox thing: I have tested Firefox 43 under an up-to-date Arch Linux system and there things display correctly (with HTML-CSS). It seems to be a bug issued from a very subtle interaction between the browser and the OS.

Comment: @alexM do both systems have local MathJax fonts?

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger: In the "About MathJax" screen both report "using web TeX fonts". Does this answer your question?

Comment: I moved the image to stack.imgur using image uploader, which makes it somewhat less external (also, direct link avoids loading ads).

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger, I think it is not issue 1009, but rather [this issue](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mathjax-users/Jy9LjItIiBI/83k8wIQgqVoJ) and [this one](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mathjax-users/OYq05MePF48/1oJr2C1NbB0J), which has been seen several times in the past.

Comment: Thanks, Davide.

Comment: @AlexM. I wonder if this improved with MathJax v2.6.1?

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger: No, unfortunately no. I'll still stick to Common HTML for a little longer.

Comment: OK. The CommonHTML should be faster at the same quality anyway.